# Why does placement of sum(case... change my answer?

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, percentage

I am looking to sum some values from a transactional database via SQL. The table has the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA 
(
    i_day Date,
    Genre String,
    randomValue String,  --can be either 'A' or 'B'
)
```

No unique. Same date, genre, value combination can appear many times.

I would like to get the percentage of the time each genre is A each day. To make sure that my query works, I simply specified a specific date to do this. However, I am getting different answers depending on my query:

Query 1:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        Genre,
        SUM(CASE WHEN randomValue LIKE 'A' THEN 1 END) AS countA,
        SUM(CASE WHEN randomValue LIKE 'B' THEN 1 END) AS countB
    FROM
        tableA
    WHERE 
        i_day = '2021-01-01' /* Arbitrary date. */
    GROUP BY
        Genre
    )
SELECT
    CAST(countA / (countA + countB) as double) AS percentageA 
FROM cte;
```

Query 2:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
        i_day,
        Genre,
        randomValue, 
        COUNT(*) AS countCombination
    FROM
        tableA
    GROUP BY
        i_day,
        Genre,
        randomValue
),
cte2 AS
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN randomValue LIKE 'A' THEN countCombination END) AS countA,
        SUM(CASE WHEN randomValue LIKE 'B' THEN countCombination END) AS countB
    FROM
        cte
    WHERE
        i_day = '2021-01-01' /* Arbitrary date. */
)
SELECT
    CAST(countA/(countA+countB) AS double)
FROM
    cte2;
```

For some reason these are returning different values for me. I think the correct thing is to do query 2, but *why* is this? I feel as though I can follow the `SUM(CASE` in semantics in query 2 but I can't understand query 1. What in English is happening in the first and why is that making it different from the second?

Comment: Your `CAST(SUM...)` expressions are needlessly complicated. You can just do `COUNT(CASE randomValue WHEN 'A' THEN 1 END)`; there's no need for `LIKE`, `CAST` or `ELSE`.

Comment: @Dai if I don’t cast them as doubles the result isn’t a decimal

Comment: You only need to cast when you divide.

Comment: What RDMBS are you using? Your second query isn't valid ISO SQL (because you can't reference column expressions defined in a `SELECT` in the same `SELECT`) - only MySQL and MariaDB allow that - and I suspect this is the cause of your problems.

Comment: @dai that was shorthand

Comment: Shorthand? Shorthand for what? **SQL doesn't have "shorthand"** and people won't know what _your_ personal shorthand notation _actually means_. If the queries in your post are not your actual queries then please remove them and put your **actual** queries instead. If we can't copy+paste your SQL into Sqlfiddle to run it then we can't help you.

Comment: I understand. Edited. However, in the SQL I am running it was written as is now, and thus this is not the cause of my problem. Additionally, do I have the cast to double right? Lastly, you wrote `COUNT(CASE` and I have `SUM(CASE`. Are these equivalent? Efficiency and results-wise.

Comment: re: equivalency: your RDBMS _should_ generate the same execution-plan for both  `COUNT` and `SUM`. I prefer `COUNT( 1 OR NULL )` because it's more readable and _expresses intent_ better than `SUM( 1 or 0 )`.

Comment: **We can't help you without sample input data and actual+expected output**. Please create an example at SqlFiddle.com.

Comment: Will do so and repost here. Lastly, is the current stack stylized format the standard? I'd love to have it like this in my editor but tab doesn't cause indents for some reason.

Comment: Your formatting is largely fine, but I did improve it now.

Comment: Please tell us what DBMS you are using. The first query gives you percentages per genre, the second query gives you an overall percentage. Of course these are different values. I made a fiddle to show a simple example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6aa57411fa4e2278c1331af1198cff0b

Comment: Query #1: Count As and Bs per genre and calculate the ratios per genre from that. Query #2: Count As and Bs per day, genre, and value, then aggregate this further to get the total count of As and Bs and calculate the ratio from that.